# Zinnia startup problems

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I am trying to get Zinnia running on a django website so I can evaluate it.  I have managed to install all its dependencies and everything just fine, and I've created a few posts using the admin tools, but now I am getting errors accessing them!

The error:

```
KeyError at /weblog/2012/10/12/test-post/

'request'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/weblog/2012/10/12/test-post/
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    'request'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 54
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/ubuntudev/webtest/twsite',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

For reference, here is my [settings.py](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?288ef156757eb838#oWIvTSfHNFEYvam4qkoclJUTidu9nhwZumYM7LjDH9g=) and my [urls.py](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?04dd0dce2f78d7bc#C94TRFc1TF5t9lKZWQW8MFIEw/SGgLPSs5fhFR8JYsc=).  The latter is admittedly a huge mess because I've been screwing around with everything I could think of.

I'm just getting my feet wet with Django, and Zinnia, so please be descriptive in your answers!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a system for delivering variables to your template called [*context processors*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) ([here's a good blog post about them)](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/). These are useful if you want to have certain pieces of information in every single template. For example, if you didn't want to have to add all the links of a navigation menu to every view/template, you could instead write a template processor to deliver those links as a list to every template.

There are some context processors that are fairly critical to most apps. One such is `django.core.context_processors.request` which passes the current request objects to every template. This allows you to access a `{{ request }}` variable in your template, which will give you information about headers etc. that the user has sent ([as well as much more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/)).

Anyway, to cut a long story short, you have disabled the above `django.core.context_processors.request` in your settings:

```
#TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#        "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
#        'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
#        'django.core.context_processors.request',
#        'django.core.context_processors.media',
#        'django.core.context_processors.static',
#        'zinnia.context_processors.version',
#)
```

so uncomment all of those and you should be fine

Comment: When I did this before posting this question, I got `Module "django.core.context_processors" does not define a "auth" callable request processor` from the admin console.  I ended up commenting them out because I saw a lot of overlap between those context processors and the other settings.py variables (like `USE_I18N`).   Clearly, I'm doing something else wrong with these context processors.  Would you like to answer it here or would you prefer I opened a different question?

Comment: `'django.core.context_processors.auth'` should be `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"`. Auth is the authentication package which is an add-on to django's core, hence it's found in the `contrib` package. I've edited my answer to reflect that